# Rails - 1 User model, but 2 Profile type models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, polymorphic-associations, railstutorial.org, sti

Just finished Michael Hartl's Tutorial, so this is kind of a newbie question.  But, after lots of searching, I have not yet been convinced of a good solution for this:

I have a single User model that captures standard attributes (name, email, password, etc.).  The validations & authentication for User have also been done using the MH's RoR Tutorial.

Now, upon sign up, I would like a new user to be able to select between a Student user or a Teacher user.  Additionally, I would like for either type of user to be able to create a profile for themselves.  The Student_Profile would be pretty basic, while the Teacher_Profile would be more extensive.

Question:

My research has led me to thinking that Single Table Inheritance might be the way to go.  I think I can just create the subclasses Teacher & Student in the User model.  However, there seems to be a lot of negative thoughts about STI.  Additionally, I'm not sure if I could then simply associate a Profile model with one of the subclass models.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: I think the simplest way is to have an is_teacher flag in the users table.  Then you can have teacher_profiles and student_profiles objects.  Probably not the best architecturally, but it would probably meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The other way would be to use [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

UPDATE:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profileable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, :as => :profileable
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, :as => :profileable
end
```

As you can see, you actually say "a teacher has a profile" and "a student has a profile". Of course, it's not strictly OO but given the fact that you're working with a **relational** database there's no real OO scenario, but only a *simulated* one - no matter if you use STI or polymorphic associations.

If you really want to be able to program (and say) "a teacher IS A user" you may want to change your db backend to an object oriented database like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org). With this in the back you have real OO at your hand and can use STI in the best sensible way.

Comment: Thank you for your response Vapire.  Can you provide a little more guidance regarding polymorphic associations?  I had looked into that also but it seems like it's a backward association for this.  In other words, it seems I would have to say:  Teacher_Profile has one User & User belongs to Teacher_Profile (when I think it should be the other way around).  Thanks